# Non-blocking Timed event in Ruby like JavaScript setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to change a property on a class a few minutes after it it initialized. I attempted to use `sleep` inside a function but it delayed execution of everything:

```
active = true

def deactivate
  sleep 120
  puts 'deactivate'
  active = false
end

deactivate
puts active
```

What I was hoping would happen is `true` would log out first then two minutes later `deactivate` would log. However, what happens is `deactivate` then `false` log out after two minutes.

In JavaScript I would do something like:

```
var active = true;
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('deactivate');
  active = false;
},120000);
console.log(active);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks overkill for this task, but you can use [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) to run a task at a future time asynchronously.

```
  def deactivate
     puts 'deactivate'
     active = false
  end

  active = true
  handle_asynchronously :deactivate, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }
```

Comment: Thanks, It is a little much for what I need now but I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: The other option is to sleep in a thread, which I would definitely recommend against in a production app.  An asynchronous job is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @ihaztehcodez using a Thread does look like it could work. What issues are there using that in production?

Comment: It would make it difficult to guarantee the action you want will actually happen.  E.g. when you deploy you will need to restart the app which will destroy the thread in the process and any sleeping threads will not finish execution.  Or something else could necessitate killing the thread.  If the action is critical, that's not good.  @spickermann recommends storing an `active_until` in the database - that actually seems like the simplest/best approach.  The code looks a bit off, but the idea is solid.  Your db will persist and you don't have to manage jobs.

Answer (score 6):

Using @ihaztehcodez's suggestion of a Thread I came up with the simple solution I was looking for:

```
Thread.new do
  sleep 120
  puts 'deactivate'
  active = false
end
```

His warning about persistence doesn't worry me in this case since I am using it for non-critical notifications. If the execution was critical then storing something in a database like @spickermann said or using a library like @k-m-rakibul-islam suggested would be the better solution.

Comment: This has been one of the more interesting questions I have been a part of.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me (When I try this code) the active and deactivate is out of order. So why not do this?:

```
   active = true

   def deactivate
     sleep 120
     puts 'deactivate'
     active = false
   end

   puts active
   deactivate
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: I need to execute more code after the `puts active` and then two minutes later active is set to false. The problem I have is the sleep inside deactivate stops execution of all code after it is called.

Comment: @KyleWerner you mean after I call 'active' it's supposed to stop

Comment: I don't want anything to stop. I want active to be true and have all code below it run. Then two minutes later active is set to false independent of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the time until it is active?

Then there is no need to block, callback or run anything async at all. When you store `active_until` in a datetime column in a database model, then it allows you keep track of changes and keep the current `active` status even over several different requests to the app:

```
def active
  active_until.blank? || Time.current < active_until
end

def deactivate
  update_columns(active_until: 2.minutes.since)
end
```

Comment: Yes I am using Rails and a computed property would work if I just needed to read the active property when needed. I need to do more logic after the timer is up like send a notification back through a websocket.

Comment: He would still need something to actually call `deactivate`.  That would lean more toward an asynchronous job, but I'm not sure how that would work with a websocket...

Comment: He could call `deactivate` himself when it is appropriate or he could do that in a callback after initialize. Note: This code does not block (like `pause` would), doesn't add external dependencies (like a background job), does not deactivate immediately, but after 2 minutes `active` will not return `true` anymore.

Comment: I feel like one of us is missing something. There was some ambiguity in the question as asked, but it later became clear Kyle needed an active callback; passively determining active status would not suffice. As you say, he would have to call it himself, which would require an external means (like a background job). I think your answer was the most elegant to the original question, but I'm not sure how it fits with the new information. Quite possible I'm missing something - it's rather late here. If that's the case, I'd appreciate if you could explain what I'm missing. :)

Comment: Yes, my original question was too vague. I'm a little new at asking questions here. What I was looking for was an asynchronous job that fired off the actions itself and didn't require checking the active property. Thanks to both of you for getting me thinking in the right direction.